# Can we describe someone as a person's "fifth forefather"?

Tags: ordinals

John's father was Max; Max's father was Jones; Jones' father was Douglas; Douglas' father was Andrew; Andrews's father was Browning; Browning's father was Smith.

Can we say?

> Browning is John's fifth forefather?

Comment: We don't use the word *forefather* that literally; it just means "a remote ancestor".  So we could say that Jones, Douglas, Andrew, etc. are John's forefathers, but we don't use the word *forefather* with ordinal numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When discussing how we are related to parents, grandparents, and those further back, we use the 'grand' prefix for the generation before our parents. My parents' fathers are my grandfathers, and my parents' mothers are my grandmothers.

For each earlier generation, we add, as a prefix, the word 'great' and a hyphen. Thus my grandmother's mother is my great-grandmother. In conversation we would not usually use very long sequences of 'greats' because people would probably get confused after three or more. We could say that Browning is John's ancestor 'five generations back'.

```
John's father was Max  
Max's father was Jones        (grandfather)   
Jones' father was Douglas     (great-grandfather)  
Douglas' father was Andrew    (great-great-grandfather)  
Andrews's father was Browning (great-great-great-grandfather)   
Browning's father was Smith   (great-great-great-great-grandfather)
```

Comment: You could also say that Smith is John's great-grandfather's great-grandfather, which avoids the excessive pileup of "great"s.

Comment: We sometimes say _Browning was John's five-greats grandfather_. It's informal (and I'm not sure how to write it, because I've probably never seen it written down), but understood.

Comment: @ColinFine - I think that in British society, outside of certain groups with special interests (e.g. genealogy nerds, the aristocracy perhaps) nobody gives a damn about people further back than their grandparents, so we don't really have to worry about greats much.